# Solution to Basic ODE using Matlab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

So I am currently taking a differential eq.s class, and am also learning how to use Matlab. I know Matlab is mostly used for numerical approximations, but I wanted to try to use the **dsolve()** command to symbolically solve some basic ODE's.

The equation in question is simply
$$v^{'} = 9.8 - \frac{v}{5},$$
For which I know the solution is $$v = 49 + ce^{-t/5}.$$

In Matlab, I input this code, including the initial condition, and it keeps giving me the wrong answer for some reason.
[Matlab code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbQbI.png)

This is pretty much the simplest ODE that can be posed, and I am having problems getting Matlab to answer it; does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For symbolic calculations other softwares are likely more powerful. You can take a look at the matlab instruction ode45 while you are at it (which is very popular for numerical solving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too complicated. Here is the solution with only 3 lines of code:

```
>> syms v(t)
>> S=dsolve(diff(v)==9.8-v/5);
>> pretty(S)

        /   t \
  C2 exp| - - | + 49
        \   5 /
>>
```

Comment: Ok, I realized now that I was making the oldest mistake in the books with my code, dividing my v by 2 instead of dividing it by 5.  But your code is much simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look again at what you wrote in your code,

```
y'(v) = 9.8-0.5*v
```

and compare with the ODE you wanted to solve

```
v'(t) = 9.5-v(t)/5
```